# NavigationLink is getting randomly popped and "Unable to present. Please file a bug."

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have 6 navigation links within a navigation view but on some of them it randomly pops back to the root and says "Unable to present. Please file a bug." in the console. Here is my code for my `NavigationView`:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupQueueSelectionView()
                .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            ,
            tag: 1,
            selection: $modelController.currentPage,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )

        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupQueueDetailsView()
                .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            ,
            tag: 2,
            selection: $modelController.currentPage,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )

        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupSigningView()
                .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            ,
            tag: 3,
            selection: $modelController.currentPage,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )

        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupRetailView()
                .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            ,
            tag: 4,
            selection: $modelController.currentPage,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )

        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupPrivacyView()
                .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            ,
            tag: 5,
            selection: $modelController.currentPage,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )

        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupSummaryView()
                .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            ,
            tag: 6,
            selection: $modelController.currentPage,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )
        EventSetupDetailView()
            .background(Color.neutral(.oneHundred))
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

    }
}
```

I've seen other stackoverflow/apple dev forum answers that talk about adding this to the NavigationView but it doesn't work for me:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
   EmptyView()
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you changing the selection for the `NavigationLink`? From what I see all of them are empty views and the text that you have on this home page does not change the selection.

Comment: @runemonster I have a separate button that increments the value of `modelController.currentPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you're meant to work with `NavigationLink` + `selection`. It should be used when you're selecting one of destinations from **current** screen, it's not meant to be changed while an other screen presenting. And in your case you're pushing new destination **before** previous disappeared, that's why it's not working.

I suggest you Chaining your views into a navigation stack:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            EventSetupDetailView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .onAppear {
                    print("hello")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct EventSetupDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupQueueSelectionView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        ) {
            Text("next")
        }
    }
}

struct EventSetupQueueSelectionView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupQueueDetailsView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        ) {
            Text("next")
        }
    }
}
struct EventSetupQueueDetailsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupSigningView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        ) {
            Text("next")
        }
    }
}
struct EventSetupSigningView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupRetailView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        ) {
            Text("next")
        }
    }
}
struct EventSetupRetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupPrivacyView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        ) {
            Text("next")
        }
    }
}
struct EventSetupPrivacyView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        NavigationLink(
            destination: EventSetupSummaryView()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        ) {
            Text("next")
        }
    }
}
struct EventSetupSummaryView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        Text("next")
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code, what is `LazyView` and `EmptyNavigationLink(destination: page...` wouldn't run so is that supposed to be `destination: page(modelController.currentPage)...`  or something else? I tried using `page(modelController.currentPage)` but it gives "generic parameter Destination can't be inferred"

Comment: @Tometoyou I forget about `LazyView`, added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks. The line `EmptyNavigationLink(destination: page, selection: $modelController.currentPage)` doesn't build because 1. it doesn't know what `page` is, and 2. if replaced with `page(modelController.currentPage)`, it can't infer the generic type. How can that be fixed?

Comment: Because essentially I want to go from `EventSetupDetailView` to `EventSetupQueueSelectionView` to `EventSetupQueueDetailsView` etc. So what you're saying is actually I need a `NavigationView` in each of these views rather than listing them all in one `NavigationView`?

Comment: @Tometoyou page is `func page(_ page: Int) -> some View {`, it should be inside the same view. Try specifying it more explicitly `EmptyNavigationLink(destination: self.page(_:), selection: $modelController.currentPage)`

Comment: @Tometoyou If you need to save backstack, to return to `EventSetupQueueSelectionView`, or if you need push navigation animation, than yes, it each view should contain link to the next one.

Comment: Okay thanks it worked just as `page`, not sure why it was throwing me an error before. I didn't realise I'd been using NavigationView wrongly and had been stuck for hours so you've definitely helped! I think I will have a NavigationLink in each view as I need to go back

Comment: Having said that, I've changed it so that theres a link in each view. This works until it gets to the third view and that gets pushed and then pops right back to the root. I think this is the swift bug talked about here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677333.

Comment: The EmptyNavigationLink way above works, but after the second page the push animation doesn't exist. It just shows the page immediately without animation. How would that be achieved?

Comment: @Tometoyou I'm not sure about issue about chaining view controllers, I've updated my answer with sample of chaining them and it seems working totally fine, check it out

Comment: Thanks. In my views the navigation links are empty views, rather than next buttons. I am using tag/selection binding from an environmentobject to make the navigation link active. I’ve also tried binding to isActive but it still doesn’t work. I think somehow the state of the binding gets reset when I push to the third view. Can you try your code with a tag/selection binding?

Comment: @Tometoyou why would you need that binding? What's wrong with the proposed variant?

Comment: Because my actual view is a little more complex - I have a button external to that view that increments a “currentPage” variable every time it’s pressed. That var is stored in my environmentobject. So I bind that value to the navigation links and tag them so they know when to display

Comment: @Tometoyou I'm not sure why do you need to store that index, but `NavigationLink` is not gonna work with it. I suggest you check on custom navigation view like [this one](https://github.com/matteopuc/swiftui-navigation-stack), where you can control whatever you want

Comment: @PhilipDukhov but what does it mean? if I have DetailView that reuse in app and a few NavigationLink to there from the different View, I have to wright down all "Back" cases to that Views from DetailView?

Comment: @Nizami I didn't get it, you better create a separate question, if this one doesn't seems answering yours.